# how to get html from xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, php, html

It difficult to me
I try to use `xmlhttprequest level 2`.
I trying to get html from url and display in div tag `id=mydiv`.
I creating `123.php` and run it in *xampp*

```
  <script>
    function createCORSRequest() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
            xhr.open("get", "http://www.ebay.com", true);
        } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
            xhr = new XDomainRequest();
            xhr.open(method, url);
        } else {
            xhr = null;
        }
        return xhr;
    }
  </script>
```

and code function getpage()

```
    function getpage() {
    var request = createCORSRequest();
      if (request) {
        request.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        };
        request.send();
      }
    }
```

code html

```
<button type="button" onclick="getpage()">Request data</button>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

How can i get the html code from it.

and how to add header xmlhtmlrequest

```
Host: www.ebay.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: vi-vn,vi;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

Can somebody help me solve problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line:

```
    request.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    };
```

To:

```
    request.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    };
```

Comment: there may be problem with "request.onload = function() {}", not called